# Weird CSS Column behavior with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working on a web application using Bootstrap, and have come across odd behaviour in my columns that I cannot seem to figure out.

Most of the CSS I'm using is just Twitter bootstrap defaults. I've attached screenshots of the HTML structure and the problem itself.

[The Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWOxJ.jpg)

It appears that the first div in my main-content div is expanding to match the size of the sidebar, which makes no sense to me.

Also upon further investigation it appears that each child within my #main-content div contains the following CSS, which causes the issue. How might I circumvent it?

```
.row-fluid:after {
    clear: both;
}

.row-fluid:before, .row-fluid:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.row-fluid:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Here is the actual page: http://d.titanlabs.ca/ai2/test.html

Comment: Frankly, at this point, I'm more interested in seeing some CSS than a DOM tree.

Comment: @remibreton It's hard to show the CSS as it's mostly just bootstrap, and there are so many different styles.

Comment: Any reason you can't use the grid system?

Comment: Thanks for adding the CSS, but I just figured, the 'Description' paragraph starts approximatively where the sidebar ends. I'm thinking there might be a `float:right;` on the sidebar, and a `clear:both;` or  `clear:right;` on the content?

Comment: @Dominic I am using the grid for most of the application, this part specifically (The sidebar and the main area) just won't work with the grid layout system. The contents of the main area do use the grid layout however

Comment: If you are using firebug, it would help if you right click on html node, copy the HTML and paste it on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @remibreton No clear on the #main-content div, but there are clears on the divs directly inside of the #main-content div.

Comment: Yaar, 'tis be a mysterious day for floats and clears. A jsfiddle could help here.

Comment: Added the full HTML/CSS source code to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be i know the reason just give `float` to your `#main-content` also. write like this:

```
#main-content {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 45px;
    padding: 25px 0;
    width:860px;
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
#main-content{
   margin-left: 45px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This actually has the effect of moving the ENTIRE #main-content div below the height of the #sidebar div

Comment: define width to your #main-content also

Comment: Adding a static width to the #main-content is problematic, but I tried it anyways and no luck.

Comment: It's a well know problem. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/qQmPb/ i recreate your issue. This issue raise when you define float to one DIV & not define float to another.