# bootstrap row height 100% issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project using the framework Twitter Bootstrap 3.

My basic HTML layout is.

- Sidebar
- Main content

The sidebar element has 100% height and `float: left` so that the div classed `main-content` stays inline.

When I give the sidebar float left property and add a `row` classed div in `main-content` div.

The height of `.row` goes crazy. But instead of `float: left` if I use `position: fixed` to the sidebar then the `.row` height gets adjusted according to content inside the `.row`.

I did play with the web console in Chrome and noticed that there are two pseudo elements created on row `:before` and `:after`.

When I unchecked the css property of those pseudo classes the height of the `.row` is to the height of the child.

Why do I have this issue when I use `float: left` to the sidebar?

How can I overcome it?

Did google on this, and I found [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493481/weird-css-column-behavior-with-twitter-bootstrap). But it doesn't help me.

Also I've created a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GeA7N/) to demonstrate the strange behaviour of the `.row` classed div where it extends to almost to screen of the height but there's nothing present inside the `.row` element.

Someone help me to get this clarified and fixed.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT : Why the height of the `.row` div is 100% when I didn't define it's height?**

Comment: I am still a little foggy on the question. You want the sidebar to the left and full screen, and you want the right side (dark grey) to be set as/to...?

Comment: No No. Everything is perfect in the layout. But the problem is.. height of the first `.row` inside the `.main-content` is 100%. But no where I've set the `.row` to be 100%. This is my problem.

Comment: Well I am pretty sure that children inherit attributes from the parent unless otherwise specified, since the parent of `row` is `main-content`, and since `main-content` is 100% height, so will `row`. And  furthermore, you also have `main-content`->`row` within `page-container`'s nest (parent to them both) which ALSO has a height of 100% so that could get passed on too.

Comment: How can I overcome it? I don't want the `.row` to be 100% height. But I want the `.page-contianer`, `.sidebar` and `.main-content` to be 100% height.

Comment: Well that is what I asked before, what DO you want the height of row to be? If you nest items and you do not want inherited attributes, then you need to give the children attributes of its own.

Comment: I want the height to be dynamic according to the elements inside `.row` div. I don't want to set the height manually.

Answer (score 6):

I find your mark-up a bit odd considering you are working with Bootstrap. Why don't you make use of the Bootstrap functionality to create your sidebar and main content div? This way you also don't run into unwanted "100% height divs".

**Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/GeA7N/3/**

```
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sidebar col-xs-4">
        </div>
        <div class="main-content col-xs-8">
            <div class="well custom-well"></div>
            <div style="background: red">Content div that is not 100% height by default</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesnt work man! here's why : when your main-content get more height than the body the the two columns will have different height, try to put more text inside the content div and you will see :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using  http://www.layoutit.com as a guide for a layout? You don't have to register to use it. Once you get the columns setup correctly you can go in and and set the height of the columns with the style attribute on the div. Hope this helps a little bit

Comment: I don't want to set the height of it. Thing is, you can find a div classed `.row` inside the `main-content` div. Inspect element with the browser console and check the height of that `.row` div. It's height is too 100% wherein I haven't defined it.

Answer (score 0):

Children inherit attributes from parents, unless otherwise specified.

So let's specify a `height` for row and it will no longer inherit.

All I am adding is a row `height` attribute to overwrite both the parent's `height` attribute.

```
.row {
    background-color:blue;
    height:50%;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GeA7N/1/)** Blue is to show the row `div`. The grey is just the underlying background of the page.

Comment: Austin - Thank you very much for the answer. But I don't want to set the `.row` height manually. I want it to be dynamic according to the height I specify to the elements inside of it.

Comment: That's slightly strange, may I ask why? Usually you would set your parent to a certain site, which would then dynamically apply attributes to all the children, doing it the other way around will require a lot more manual work. Can you add some example code or a visual (like paint) reference so that I can see what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: If that's the case. Any child of the `.main-content` should be of height 100% right? But that doesn't happen until and unless I give the div class as `.row`. Height gets to 100% only when the child has the class `.row`.

Comment: I gotta see examples of code, there are exceptions like using "row" and such. But seeing code, and seeing what you are trying to do is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT : Why the height of the .row div is 100% when I didn't define
>   it's height?

**Reason:** The `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements of the `.row` class have the style `display:table;` thereby causing your first row to fill as much remaining space as it can.

**Solution:** To avoid overriding the Bootstrap framework, simply encapsulate your `.container` class with another div which has the style `display:flex;`